# How do you select the 10 best images from a set of 300?

Tags: workflow, curation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's a good strategy for choosing which photos to keep?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8236/whats-a-good-strategy-for-choosing-which-photos-to-keep)

I have read that photographers are rarely the best editors of their own images. As digital cameras make it so easy to take hundreds of shots of a given subject, the challenge of sorting and ranking them to come up with the handful of great images to share/print/publish has become so monumental that it is almost hopeless. What tools and techniques do you use to perform this task of curating images?

Comment: See also this question which may be of some use: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8236/whats-a-good-strategy-for-choosing-what-to-keep