# Do you keep all of your photos?

Tags: file-management, storage

Even though I do a quick edit in camera to remove unwanted shots as I shoot, I still end up with a huge number of shots. I keep and back up in the cloud the ones I am working on for a project and catalog them into projects and locations.

But what about all the rest, do you keep them all and put into a 'random' folder? Get rid?

It frustrates me having a load of photographic clutter just sitting there but MAYBE, I'll use them one day?

What do you do?

Comment: I do. It's a terrible habit. But disc storage is cheap these days so I indulge. It would be better to ruthlessly cull. Or at least delete the obvious losers. But you never know when you may see an interesting crop inside a seemingly mediocre photo. I can never get rid of photos.

Comment: These sort of questions are generally not well received on photo.SE. Look at http://photo.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask and you'll find that it tells us to avoid questions where every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?” and your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”- It can be rephrased as a question about pros and cons about saving all photos, but that has already been covered here i think: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7130/how-many-photos-should-i-keep.

Comment: And here http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8236/whats-a-good-strategy-for-choosing-which-photos-to-keep

Comment: Didn't actually ever read that page Hugo, cheers for the heads up. I'll bear this in mind for future posts.

Comment: I keep everything.  I preview them, identify and rate the top few ~ usually about 10% of the set.  I keep them all together because I've titled my folder with a date and either event or location, (e.g. 2014_08_19 Anytown).  The rating lets me work on just the few that I thought were keepers.  -  Then, I make a back up copy of everything, all at once.  I used to make two copies with second for offsite storage, but I've fallen out of the habit.  So, I have multiple copies of my images, 90% of which I will never touch again.  Nonetheless, I have my reasons to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I do keep a backup of every picture that I capture via my camera. I love to take 1000 pics of some random thing from different angles. That leaves me with hell of a choices. I have options to use any one of them. I edit the one I love & keep the rest of the pics stored in cloud. See, the best thing about the cloud storage is they are free & can be accessed from anywhere. Well...if you find yourself out of memory in your cloud storage space, take a new account. I think sky drive comes with 15 gb of free space, same is with google drive or dropbox or etcetra etcetra etcetra. So, I recommend you to keep a backup of all photos. Photography is not about which pic you love...it's about which pic others love. You may love a snap that you captured with lot of efforts. But sometimes it may look like shit to someone else. Taste is different for everyone. who knows one day some one will say to you that the pic that you hate the most is the pic that he/she loves the most. Gracias.

I suggest you to make multiple directories based on the year or month the pics are taken. Store pics in 'em.

Comment: Same here. Google Drive is super affordable nowadays. Something like 100GB for $3 per month.